# How to run python commands in a new terminal window

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I am learning django. I am stuck with this problem.

So basically, I have designed a form (template) in HTML that takes a text file as input and generates a voiceover of that text file. I am using `espeak` for it in the backend.
So, when a user uploads a file, this command
`espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt`
where `sample.txt` is the name of the uploaded file should run in a new terminal window.

[image: sample output]
As you can see in the above image this is what I want to achieve. Here, `sample.txt` is the name of the text file. I want to achieve this by the python program instead of doing it manually.

As I already said I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Edit:
I tried to run this command
`subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--', f"espeak -ven+m1 -f {uploaded_file.name}"])`
But the output I am getting is this
`There was an error creating the child process for this terminal Failed to execute child process “espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt” (No such file or directory)`

[image: new shell output]

Also please note that `Run a custom command instead of my shell` checkbox is **untick**

Comment: Why do you need an actual shell for that? Wouldn't be enough just spawning a new process to execute `espeak` in the background? See the "Subprocess" module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: @BorrajaX Do you mean something like this subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', print("espeak -ven+m1 -f", uploaded_file.name)]). This is not working.

Comment: Oh... do you wanna play the sound in the server? I though you wanted to generate some sort of .mp3 file or something. If so, you could try something along the lines of `subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--', f"espeak -ven+m1 -f {uploaded_file.name}")` ?  

More here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command

Comment: @BorrajaX I am unable to achieve what I want. I have made my problem clearer. Maybe you can have a look and suggest me something.

Comment: Print just prints on screen solution that @BorrajaX suggested is right. Please post what you are trying until then ppl cant actually help

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I have made the necessary corrections.

Comment: @BorrajaX Your method helped after some changes.

Comment: Give full path of sample.txt your current working directory for python program is different